# Stack Exchange podcast episode 28 download blues

Tags: bug, status-completed, podcast

How can Stack Exchange podcast [episode 28](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-28-brent-ozar/) be downloaded?

Previous episodes have a download link on their [SoundCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundCloud) page. For instance, on the [page for episode 27](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-27) the link is `http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-27/download`. The supposed link for episode 28,

```
http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-28/download
```

redirects back `http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-28`.

Comment: Hmm, this one isn't listed as downloadable (off of Sound Cloud) like the rest of them.  :-/

Comment: http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/28804935-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-28.mp3 works btw.

Comment: @chown: thanks, it works. How did you find the number (28804935) for episode 28? Some previous numbers: 25906939 for episode 23, 26443821 for episode 24 and 28160568 for episode 27.

Comment: @Peter I added a screenshot below of the link I used.

Comment: @chown: NoScript (in Firefox) blocked the Flash and JavaScript part so I did not see it (but the link is in the page source)

Comment: @P Ah, glad you found it.  Its an interesting listen, as always.

Comment: @chown: indeed it is. I usually download the podcast episodes through a download script (using Wget) using the predictable SoundCloud URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download it using the technique that Chown suggested.

But I also re-enabled downloading it via SoundCloud, so you can grab it there.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded it earlier via the download link at the end of the blog.

> SE Podcast #28 - Brent Ozar [ 59:48 ] Download

Links to:

http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/28804935-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-28.mp3

Just tested again and it still works.

Heres a screenshot in response to your comment:

[image]

Comment: (I will hold off accepting the answer for a few days.)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to extract the ID number from the page source for the SoundCloud page and construct the download URL. This should make the podcast available somewhat earlier than relying on the Stack Exchange blog.

For [episode 28](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-28), the ID number is 28804935 and appears three times. For instance:

```
<div class="player mode large haudio  " data-sc-track="28804935"><div class="info-header large"><div class="meta-data"><div class="key-bpm"><span class="track-type">Podcast</span></div></div>
```

The download URL can be constructed thus:

```
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/28804935-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-28.mp3
```

The first or second line containing `data-sc-track` may be robust enough, but as with all [screen-scraping](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screen-scrape) it may be subject to change without notice.